# Finetuning how the date is displayed after adding it to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, dateadd

Just starting to write VBA here, raw beginner.

I'm looking for help in fine-tuning my displayed date. With the help of examples I found online, I have a module to put the name of the last month, and year, into a cell in my Totals worksheet, and it does what I need to get by.

To make it perfect, though, I'd like to change what date info is displayed.

This is Excel in Office 365. I've searched for examples online and read tutorials about using DateAdd but can't find this anywhere. (Part of the problem is I'm so new, I don't know how to phrase things in vba-speak to find good answers!)

What I use now:

```
Sub PreviousMonthBasedOnCurrentMonth()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Totals")

ws.Range("A1") = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy")

End Sub
```

This now inserts "February 1, 2019" into the cell - which is enough data for me to confirm which month I'm looking at. But ideally I'd like "February 1-28, 2019" (Or, say, "October 1-31, 2019" if I'm running this while in Nov).

How do I get the 'first day of month - last day of month' portion to display? Is that part of DateAdd, or more coding from scratch?

Not sure how to write something like that myself. Pointers to where to start would be great.

Comment: If you want the whole month, why not display as October, 2019?

Comment: Because in some rare cases, I make a partial report - which is indicated in title of the partial report and other places, and the date is entered manually. I'd just like one more visual reminder that I'm working on a complete month report.

Comment: And eventually I will be editing an old, inherited, complicated macro and adding this on to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim dt, dt2

dt = DateAdd("m", -1, Date) 'this time last month

dt2 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) - 1 'last day of previous month

Debug.Print Format(dt2, "mmmm") & " 1-" & Day(dt2) & " " & Format(dt2, "yyyy")
```

Note Excel will not see this as a date though...

Comment: It's fine if it's not an actual Excel date, it's truly just for a visual reminder, nothing to be acted upon later. Specific actual date-dates are in the file elsewhere. (Thank you for pointing that out, I hadn't thought of mentioning that in my question)

Comment: So far this seems to be working, off to test it included inside of some of my more complicated macros, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it on one line this way:

```
Debug.Print Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm") & " 1-" & Format(CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), 0)), "dd, yyyy")
```

OR

```
Debug.Print Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm") & YourPartialDateVariableHere & Format(CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), 0)), "dd, yyyy")
```